# Is a Python Webscraper a Wrapper?

Tags: python

Would a simply Python Script to extract Information from a Webpage (e.g with use of beautiful soup for example) be called a Wrapper (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_(data_mining))?

Answer (score 1):

It might be, or it might not. It depends on how it performs.

The key to a wrapper in the more general sense is that it provides for the interoperability of two distinct classes of object which are not inherently able to work together.

In the specific case you are talking about, simply creating a script to scrape the web is not necessarily a wrapper. Once you format the xml into a recognized format such as JSON, pandas dataframe or  in a SQL schema that your program can operate over, it becomes a wrapper.

The wrapper 'repackages' the data to work in your current system's class transparently so that you do not see the underlying nature of the incompatible structure.